# UI design for Multiple Screen sizes

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I had developed an android app with `RealtiveLayout` but when I run on small screen devices the fields are overlapping.

How can I get the width and height of the device programatically so that it is easier for to adjust the screen size

Comment: Please share your code, Have you updated your code in layout-xdpi,hdpi,mdpi etc.

Comment: Did you design according to the guidelines http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html ?

Comment: Use wrap content as height and width of views and place them in a scrollView.

Comment: Can you please put your xml ?

Comment: have you tried using weight in your xml layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />


    <!-- support for Xperia Z, Galaxy S4 and HTC One -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="normal" /> 
    <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="large" /> 
    </compatible-screens>
```

Try this code in the manifest I think this will work.. 
Other wise Create separate folders in res folder like layout-small, layout-large, layout-normal, and use appropriate images in the drawable folder drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi... I am sure this will help you for various screen orientation..

Answer (score 0):

Use Horizontall ScrollView for that then it looks perfect on small devices also.

Comment: Horizontal Scroll view is to use "horizontal scroll". You should do this kind of operations with layouts. You should not use hsv as a layout itself.

Comment: yes I also means the same Inside your layout use the horizontal scrollview